# Deleting the item and creating table using javascript

Tags: javascript, flask-wtforms

In this wtform I have to add set of program id, program_name,program_description. After entering all these details I have to click the schedule button. Once it clicked the table will be created in the bottom of the page. Those details are not stored in the database. It will be stored as a list. Once I click the remove button the data has to be removed from the list and it should get deleted from the table row also. So I tried ajax and passes the data to the backend and removed the id from the list and passed it back to front end. Now I tried to create a table in the javascript with the list I struck over there. is ther any other way to do this?

```
<div>
    <form method="POST", action="">

        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend>Add Students</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.program_id.label(class="col-sm-1 col-form-label")}}
                {{form.program_id(id="program_id")}}
            </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.program_name.label(class="col-sm-1 col-form-label")}}
                {{form.program_name(id="program_name")}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.program_description.label(class="col-sm-1 col-form-label")}}
                {{form.program_description(id="program_description")}}

            </div>         
           

            <div class="form-group" align ="justify">

                {{form.cancel(class="btn btn-outline-info")}}
                {{form.schedule(class="btn btn-outline-info")}}
            </div>

            <table class="table table" border =1 >
                <tr >
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>program_id</th>
                    <th>program_title</th>
                    <th>program_description</th>
                </tr>
                {% for program in all_programs %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{program.program_id}}</td>
                    <td> {{program.program_title}}</td>
                    <td> {{program.program_description}}</td>

                    <td>

                    <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeProgram(this)" data-program-id="{{program.program_id}}" data-program-list="{{program_list}}">
                    </td>

                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>

    </form>

    
    <script>
        function removeProgram(deleteaction){
            programId = deleteaction.getAttribute('data-program-id');
            programList = deleteaction.getAttribute('data-program-list');
            console.log("we are here", articleId,articleList)
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/removeaprogram',
                data:{
                    'programid':programId,
                    'programlist':programList
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)  // display the returned data in the console.
                    let optionTable = '<table class="table table" border =1 ><tr ><th>ID</th><th>program_id</th><th>program_title</th><th>program_description</th></tr>';
                    for(each_data in data){
                        optionTable = "'<tr><td>'+{{each_data.program_id}}+'</td>''<td>'+{{each_data.program_title}}+'</td>'"
                    }
                

                   
          

            })

        }
    </script>



</div>
```

Comment: you need to concate optionTable in the loop, you are overwriting it. Once HTML string is ready you can push it to any of the html element.

Comment: IF this is not server related, then please post RENDERED HTML in a [mcve]. Click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 0):

This is not ok for several reasons

```
for(each_data in data){
  optionTable = "'<tr><td>'+{{each_data.program_id}}+'</td>''<td>'+{{each_data.program_title}}+'</td>'"
}
```

1. The `=` keeps assigning over and over
2. JavaScript does not use {{}}
3. You are not actually inserting the table anywhere - No need to change the complete table

You may have better luck with

```
 document.querySelector(".table tbody").innerHTML = data
  .map(`<tr><td>${data.program_id}</td>
            <td>${data.program_title}</td>
        </tr>`).join("");
```

assuming a JSON response of

```
[{"program_id":"ID1", "program_title":"Title 1"},
 {"program_id":"ID2", "program_title":"Title 2"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create table string as HTML. Closing `tr` tag was missing in the loop. Once loop is over , you can push this to any of the HTML element.

```
success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)  // display the returned data in the console.
                    let optionTable = '<table class="table table" border =1 ><tr ><th>ID</th><th>program_id</th><th>program_title</th><th>program_description</th></tr>';
                    for(each_data in data){
                        optionTable = optionTable +  "'<tr><td>'+{{each_data.program_id}}+'</td>''<td>'+{{each_data.program_title}}+'</td></tr>'"
                    }
                    document.getElementById('tableArea').innerHTML = optionTable ; // Add table to HTML doc or any div or area
            })
```